# What does -> mean in eachWithIndex?

Tags: groovy

In Groovy, what does this -> (arrow) mean?

Example:

```
List<MyObject> myObjectList =  MyObject.findAllByName("XXX");

myObjectList.eachWithIndex{ item, index ->
   println item.age
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Groovy Closure syntax.

> A closure definition follows this syntax:
>
> `{ [closureParameters -> ] statements }`
>
> Where `[closureParameters->]` is
>   an optional comma-delimited list of parameters, and statements are 0
>   or more Groovy statements. The parameters look similar to a method
>   parameter list, and these parameters may be typed or untyped.

See http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html